# How do I create a group of different UI elements in XAML based on datatypes of the bound values?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a list of parameters in an Observable Collection in my ViewModel that I want to be displayed as textboxes or comboboxes dependent on the datatype, but I'm struggling to find a way to implement any kind of conditional functionality in XAML.

So, say I have an observable collection of parameters (title, datatype, value):

> Valid,Boolean,
>
> Name,String,
>
> Age,UInt,

I currently have these generating a sequence of textboxes in the window next to labels indicating the type and parameter name using:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Textbox Text="{Binding Value}"
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But I don't want this to be a textbox every time; I want to be able to have something like an "if" or a "switch" to make a combobox instead if the datatype facilitates pre-defined responses like True/False.

I've seen similar posts where the answers seemed to suggest using `Triggers` or `DataTriggers` to do this, which looks exactly like what I need. However, they always seem to put it in a `Style`, with `Style.Triggers`, rather than any of the elements I currently have. Any attempts to replicate what I've seen have failed due to slight differences in what we've used; The example will use something like ContentControl and bind the style with "Content = {…}" which I can't do because "Content" isn't something I can apply to "ItemControl", but I need ItemControl due to the way it implements `ObservableCollection` in a way Content control doesn't.

Is there a simple way to put "If datatype == Boolean, make a combobox here" sort of thing? If I can make this happen in the ViewModel, I'm open to that too. Don't want to be doing anything in the code-behind, as MVVM doesn't seem to play nice with it and has always bit me in the behind later down the road when I try to mix them and I can't get my values to interact properly.

Would very much appreciate any help.
I realise I could just have the user TYPE true/false and interpret it in the viewmodel as Boolean, but there's several reasons this won't really work in my case. For one thing, there will be many, many options.

Comment: Have a look at [ItemTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Really think you should be using DataTemplates:

```
... xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}">
            <Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Value}" />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You can use your own types as well that it will auto detect and use the datatype for.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Joel. The datatypes I want to vary the response with are strings, but I can kind of see what you mean in terms of making my own datatypes. Feel like I'd have to make another xmlns? Maybe? to the viewmodel. I changed the "Value"s to all be Boolean and copied the code you put here, but no checkboxes appeared, suggesting it didn't work. Not sure what to do about that.